# How to call View using AJAX call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to call view using AJAX call with ASP.net MVC2.0 but it doesn't work fine.  This is an AJAX method

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '../Inventoryhealth/IHView?mac=' + val + '&name=' + val2 + '#fragment-3',
          //url: '../Chart/CreateChart2?chartType=Column&a=null',
          success: function (result) {
          var res = result;
          if (res != null && res == "1")
              alert('System information can\'t be retrieved');
          }
      });
```

but if I use this it works fine

```
location.href = "../Inventoryhealth/IHView?mac=" + val + "&name=" + val2 + "#fragment-3";
```

This is view code

```
public ActionResult IHView(String mac, string name)
    {
          try
          {
              ViewData["PollTime"] = new ClientConfigurationService().getPollTime() * 60000;
              SystemInventoryService sis = new SystemInventoryService();
              SystemInformation systemInfo = new SystemInformation();
              systemInfo = sis.getSystemInventory(mac);
              systemInfo.ChartRefreshInterval = getInterval();
              systemInfo.OName = name;
              bool MoreCores = true;
               if (Convert.ToInt16(systemInfo.NumberOfCores) < 2)
              {
                  systemInfo.Core1UsageDetail = "0";
                  systemInfo.Core2UsageDetail = "0";
                  MoreCores = false;
              }

              Add(systemInfo.ProcessorLoadPercentage,   systemInfo.MemoryTotalVirtualMemorySize, systemInfo.MemoryFreeVirtualMemory, systemInfo.DrivesSize, systemInfo.DrivesTotalFreeSpace, MoreCores, systemInfo.Core1UsageDetail, systemInfo.Core2UsageDetail);

            var AC = new ActiveClient();
            AC.ClientMac = mac;
            if (db.ActiveClients.Count() > 0)
            {
                db.DeleteObject(db.ActiveClients.First());
            }
            db.AddToActiveClients(AC);
            db.SaveChanges();

            if (systemInfo != null)
            {
                return View(systemInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                // If Healh and status can't be retrieved                    
               // Response.Redirect("../Inventoryhealth/InventoryIndex?error=1");
                return Content("1");
            }

        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: When you looked with FireBug at the server response how did it look like?

Comment: You don't call Views, you call actions which can return `ViewResult`s which render a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of using Post, use Get method. There is no data option in the call so it means you don't need posting. I hope it will work on changing Post to get.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing ".." while specifying the URL. THat should work fine. You could also  use firebug to see that URL is being requested from the server.

Comment: sory for this Question i dont know to check that view assigned the url or not. how it could be check?

Comment: @RizawShahid: Put a breakpoint in your controller and see if the request is at least making it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's $.get rather than the lower level $.ajax function. You want to perform an http GET not  a post in this cause.

Try something like this:

```
$.get('../Inventoryhealth/IHView?mac=' + val + '&name=' + val2 + '#fragment-3', function(data){
//do something on success
alert(data);
});
```

[jQuery Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Also.. I noticed you have a hash in your url (#). You will need to url encode this or it will return a 404.